# Inline XSD schema into an XML document

Tags: xml, xsd

I wondering if there's a way to define xsd schema directly into an xml document.
I see somthing like this write on MSXML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
         xmlns:x="urn:book"> 
<!-- START OF SCHEMA -->
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="urn:book">
 <xsd:element name="book">
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="author" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="title" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="genre" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="price" type="xsd:float"/>
      <xsd:element name="publish_date" type="xsd:date"/>
      <xsd:element name="description" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:string"/>
  </xsd:complexType>
 </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
<!-- END OF SCHEMA -->
   <x:book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications with
      XML.</description>
   </x:book>
</catalog>
```

There's something like in standard XML ?

Just to present you the context, I've got a code that dynamicaly create an XML and his XSD and sent the XML through a one stream. So my goal is to provide the XML with his schema at the same time.

Any ideas ? Is it possible ? Or the schema MUST be web accessible before sent my XML through my stream ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a possible solution](http://www.herongyang.com/XML/XSD-Statements-Embedded-in-XML-File.html) you will want to make sure your XML parser will deal with it OK.

Comment: Hi, thank's for your answer. I've try this but it's not seems be normalized, XMLs with XSD define by #xsdID don't pass XML validators like [link](http://www.validome.org/xml). And my XML can be sent to many different servers through WPS requests (Web Processing Service) and I can't send requests with non valid and non standard XML.